# std::chrono compare without date

Tags: c++, std, c++-chrono

with

```
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> from_time={};
    std::tm tm{};
    istringstream iss{input_string};
    err = !(iss >> std::get_time(&tm, "%R"));
    from_time += std::chrono::seconds(std::mktime(&tm));
```

I can convert a String like "19:00" to a time-point (which then is at a date in the past)

but I don't care about a date.

Next I want to get the current time like

```
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

But here we have a time-point with the current date, and I can not compare both time-points just for the time (what I want is: is the current time past "19:00" - yes or no. )

Is there a way to do such a comparison that uses no old C-style time handling and works independent from the date?

Is there a way to offset a time-point e.g. shift the "19:00" time-point to the current date?

Comment: Compare duration instead of time point.

Comment: Probably you can find start of day time point by something like `std::chrono::floor<std::chrono::days>(now)` and then subtract start of day from `now` and you will have only time. PS: If you don't have std::chrono::days you can use std::ratio<86400>

Comment: Do you want to compare local time?  Or is comparing time-of-day UTC sufficient?

Comment: local time is better or I need to calculate a UTC time from what the user configures (which is his local time)... by the way I already succeeded in getting the job done with the old time structure... It's not pure C++ but works nicely. But I really think it should be doneable with pure std::chrono

Comment: Pure C++20 `std::chrono` will do this job.  However the results will be "bumpy" over things like daylight saving shifts where local times can happen twice in the same day.

Comment: I know its not a perfect solution regarding daylight saving shifts and such... but for my current application this is not an issue. So if it can be done with std::chrono, can you supply some example code?